# adding a column to DataFrame based on operations of surrounding rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using this example DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,15,-30,25,4], columns=['value'])
```

I would like to add a column to this DataFrame, 'newcol' where the value in the rows is based on a function of that row, the one above it, and the one below it. for example, the function could be 2*(value in that row) - 1*(value in row above) - 1*(value in row below). NaNs are acceptable in the case of the first and last row.

so in this example, the desired output for 'newcol' would be

[image]

I was trying to make use of .apply with lambda functions but having difficulty understanding how to refer to the neighboring rows in the operation

Comment: hint: use `shift` to get all the values aligned into a single row

Comment: i agree with @roganjosh giving a readymade answer isn't difficult, but please try seeing `shift` docs and if you still fail, we will help :)

Comment: perfect, so something like: 2*df['value']-df['value'].shift(-1)-df['value'].shift(1)

Comment: Pretty much that, but you're going to get `NaN` at either end I think, so you'll need to deal with that. Nicely done.

Comment: @laszlopanaflex see, you know the answer. :) Good one